# Save State Editor Game (Checkbox)?

Tags: vb6

I like make save state editor game but I have small problem and I hope someone help me for that is problem.

```
Public Sub SaveState(pFile As String)
    If pFile = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim FF As Long
    FF = FreeFile()
    Open pFile For Binary As FF
        ' Save the Lives
        If chkLive.value = 1 Then Put #FF, 117290 + 1, 1
    Close #FF
End Sub
```

When I click in checkbox then save as, It is change TwoByte not Curval ?

Example:
In the save file game is live 02 but when I saved then I check in file I see like this:0200, I wonder what is wrong I do?

Answer (score 0):

The `, 1` that you are writing out is a 2-byte integer and so is writing two bytes.  Try

```
Public Sub SaveState(pFile As String)
    If pFile = "" Then Exit Sub
    Dim FF As Long
    Dim b as Byte
    FF = FreeFile()
    Open pFile For Binary As FF
        ' Save the Lives
        b = 1
        If chkLive.value = 1 Then Put #FF, 117290 + 1, b
    Close #FF
End Sub
```

That way only one byte will be written to the file.